# In C, why does this "backwards" indexing work?

Tags: c, indexing

Consider the following:

```
int main() {
        int a[] = {42, 9001, -1337};
        printf("%d, %d\n", a[0], 0[a]);
        return 0;
}
```

I didn't see `0[a]` before, but it appears to do the same as `a[0]` (the same appears to be true for other numbers as well, not just for `0`).

Is that my compiler's fault (GCC)? Is there any documentation on this behavior? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`a[0]` is the same as `*(a+0)`
`0[a]` is the same as `*(0+a)`

We know that `a+0` is same as `0+a`.So `*(a+0)==*(0+a)` which would mean that `a[0]==0[a]`.

Comment: It was referenced in [r/programminghorror](https://www.reddit.com/r/programminghorror/comments/v7pyc8/comment/ibm1i77/?utm_source=bob&utm_medium=nokia5110), but in a positive way.

Answer (score 5):

`a[0]` is another form of `*(a + 0)` , which can be rewritten as `*(0 + a)`,  which can be rewritten as `0[a]`

So, essentially, `a[0]` and `0[a]` represents the same.

There is no fault or error from your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `a[0]`. compiler will make it to `*(a+0).`

So you are giving the `0[a]`. It will make that as `*(0+a)`. So it is working.